# How do I check if output stream of a socket is closed?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, outputstream

I have this code:

```
public void post(String message) {
    output.close();
    final String mess = message;
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    output.println(mess);
                    System.out.println("The following message was successfully sent:");
                    System.out.println(mess);
                    break;
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

As you can see I close the socket in the very beginning of the code and then `try` to use it to send some information to another computer. The program writes me "The following message was successfully sent". It means that the NullPointerException was not thrown.

**So, does Java throw no exception if it tries to use a closed output stream of a socket? Is there a way to check if a socket is closed or opened?**

**ADDED**

I initialize the socket in the following way:

```
clientSideSocket = new Socket(hostname,port);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSideSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
browser.output = out;
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of output?
How is it initialized?
The exception your code should throw isn't NullPointerException but IOException.

Comment: I added the code which I use to initialize the socket. Andrea, you say that IOException should be thrown. But it is not thrown. Why?

Comment: Don't know. From the PrintWriter source it should.
Only problem I can think about is some sort of synchronization problem (you close the writer in a thread and use in a different one, possibly executing in a different core), but I'm not really expert in this field. EDITED: try to move the creation of the PintWriter inside the thread.

Comment: What happens if you declare your `output` member variable as `volatile`?

Comment: @Andrea The thread is created in the same thread that closes the output. It's guaranteed that output.close() completed at the time the other thread starts execution.

Comment: @sfussenegger as I already said I was wrong, it isn't a synchronization problem

Answer (score 7):

I should have looked better. From the javadoc of PrintWriter:

> Methods in this class never throw I/O
>   exceptions, although some of its
>   constructors may.  The client may
>   inquire as to whether any errors have
>   occurred by invoking {@link
>   #checkError checkError()}.

Answer (score 3):

(a) Don't use PrintStream or PrintWriter over the network, as they suppress exceptions. They are really only for log files, or the console, where you don't care all that much. Over a network you are engaging in a protocol and you need to know about failures straight away.

(b) Socket.isClosed() returns true if you've closed either its input or its output. NB it *doesn't* tell you whether the other guy has closed the connection - that's not its function. Only reading an EOS can tell you that.