# How do I catch errors when piping to/from javas stdin/stdout

Tags: java, io, try-catch

I have a java application taking data from `stdin` and writing results to `stdout`. Like this:

```
app1 | java_app | app2
```

The amount of data moved through the pipe is large and takes a long time (hours and days is not uncommon or unexpected).

Its seems that if `app1` dies, and closes its end of the pipe, I receive a pipe related exception. However is `app2` dies, and closes its end of the pipe I do not receive an exception.  This means that `java_app` continues on consuming input, which will never generate any useful output, running for hours or days.

The difference in pipe exception reporting seems to stem from `System.in` being an `InputStream`, while `System.out` is a `PrintStream` and `PrintStream`s swallow up any errors. I know you can get the error state from a `PrintStream` by using `stream.checkError()` - but using that everywhere is clunky (and forces a flush of your output stream.)
I 'm happy to forgo the bulk of functionality of `PrintStream` to get better error reporting.

Is there another way to get access to stdout that isn't wrapped in a `PrintStream`, but instead a nicer `OutputStream`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get java to exit when piped to head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695500/how-do-i-get-java-to-exit-when-piped-to-head)

Comment: @Raedwald - IMO its not a dupe - but its related. The top answer there wasn't appropriate for this example (as it involved the use of `checkError()`). The second answer is an alternate approach that links back to this question. (i.e. now that I have a solution I added the alternative option to the other.)

Comment: Using 2 different approaches to answer one question does not give you 2 different questions.

Comment: I wrote the other question, and in my opinion, they're basically the same. I used the example of piping output into `head`, but that's a specific instance of the general issue of the output pipe being closed and wanting to detect and handle that case somehow.

Comment: I've rolled the additional info here into part of my answer on the linked question. So I'll close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of my colleagues found a nice way to do this.

```
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
```