# How to check whether a PrintStream is open without printing to it

Tags: java, io, pipe

I have a GUI program written in Java which outputs data to the command line using `System.out.println`.  The data is intended to be piped into another program.  As an example, I'll pipe the program through `head`:

```
$ java MyProgram | head -n10
```

I want my program to exit when the pipe is broken: in this case, this should happen after `MyProgram` has printed out ten lines of text.

There is [a similar question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695500/how-do-i-get-java-to-exit-when-piped-to-head), and the solution given there works fairly well; for example, I could have the following running in its own thread:

```
while(!System.out.checkError()) {
    // sleep 100ms
}
System.exit(0);
```

The problem is that `PrintStream.checkError()` seems to return `true` only after you have tried to print to the stream and failed.  For that reason, my program does not in fact exit until it has printed out *eleven* lines of text: the pipe is broken after the first ten, but `System.out` continues to return `true` until I try to pipe through the eleventh line.

Printing out extra 'junk' lines in order to trigger an error on the `PrintStream` is out of the question, since the program on the right hand side of the pipe may be very sensitive to the data it receives.

Calling `System.out.flush()` inside the loop has no effect on `PrintStream.checkError()`, even though the source code for `PrintStream` indicates that it ought to call the private `ensureOpen` method in that class.

How can I reliably test whether `System.out` is open without printing anything to it?

---

**'Real world' example:** suppose that I have some program `consumer` that takes in command line input and does something with it. Certain pieces of input will call `consumer` to fail silently.  Since the input to `consumer` is sometimes long and abstruse, I write a GUI program `InputProvider` in Java where I can click buttons and have the corresponding commands printed out to `stdout`.  If I pipe the output of `InputProvider` into `consumer`, then I am able to control `consumer` graphically.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way for `InputProvider` to notify the user when `consumer` has shut down, except by attempting to write to `consumer` and getting an exception of some kind.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You need to clarify why you think it's not OK to fail on the 11th line of output.  The underlying mechanism by which all this happens is in the OS, not in Java, and the broken pipe indication doesn't happen until you try to write.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't think it's an XY problem.  I want my input program to shut down when the program on the other side of the pipe shuts down.  Perhaps the `head` example is misleading.  At the very least, I want my input program to be able to tell whether or not the other program has quit.  The only mechanism of communication between the two is the pipe, which corresponds to the state of `System.out`.

Comment: Then as I said, that is not possible without some other communication channel. The pipe is handled by the OS and the error cannot occur until you attempt to write to the pipe.  In other words, attempting flow control by using a broken pipe is an incorrect approach that cannot be made to work.

Comment: Could you elaborate how can you say that the pipe is broken after 10 lines ? It seems you have a way to know if the pipe is broken by looking at the output lines. The fact that 11th line appeared in output means the IO is intact until then.

Comment: @svasa The 11th line does not appear in the output, but `MyProgram` does not quit.  In this case, this is not a problem, since I can tell that `head` has quit since it is no longer producing output.  But, for another program that does not print its input straight out, I might not be able to tell that that program had quit.

Comment: By looking at your latest description , I think you should do something like : `while( consumer.ready() && printStream.checkError() ) { printStream.print(...) )`. Now if you don't have some means like `ready()`, you cannot say upfront that the pipe is in tact or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can fix this in Java. There's nothing wrong with `System.out` until you write to it and it fails. Another process (`head`) ended but the Java process can't know about that.

So I think that you have two options.

1. don't use pipe to `head` but limit the output in your Java code - then you'll know when to stop
2. accept that the last line will fail and handle the exception appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a new stream for the system that way you'll be able to check if that stream is closed or not: `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("c:\\data\\system.out.txt");` and `PrintStream printOut = new PrintStream(output);`. Then set it here: `System.setOut(printOut);` and inside the if you can check `if(printOut.checkError())`