# Get HttpServletRequest state in order to avoid IllegalStateException

Tags: java, servlets, web, illegalstateexception

Sometimes the method `req.startAsync()` from `HttpServletRequest` throws an `IllegalStateException` (Response has been closed already).

How can I check the request state in order to avoid `IllegalStateException`?

`req.isAsyncSupported()` returns true always.

Relevant code:

```
final HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession(false);  
if (httpSession == null) {  
    resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);  
    return;  
}  
final AsyncContext asynContext = req.startAsync(); //exception here`
```

Exception:

> 12:28:12,735 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/esus].[LongPollServlet]]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   LongPollServlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   JBWEB000049: Response has been closed already     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:3180)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:3170)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:925)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   com.performer.framework.server.LongPollServlet.continueDoPost(LongPollServlet.java:75)
>   [st10.framework.webserver.jar:]   at
>   com.performer.framework.server.LongPollServlet.doPost(LongPollServlet.java:62)
>   [st10.framework.webserver.jar:]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]  at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
>   [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:915)
>   [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]

Comment: Do you have any redirection or forwarding in your servlets?

Comment: No redirection or fowarding

Comment: Are you using Tomcat or JBoss(Tomcat included)?

Comment: Can you post code also?

Comment: By the way, do you have any filters?

Answer (score 2):

Acording to documentation for [startAsync()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync%28%29):

> Throws: IllegalStateException - if this request is within the scope of
>   a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations
>   (that is, isAsyncSupported() returns false), or if this method is
>   called again without any asynchronous dispatch (resulting from one of
>   the AsyncContext#dispatch methods), is called outside the scope of any
>   such dispatch, or is called again within the scope of the same
>   dispatch, or if the response has already been closed.

It seems that Tomcat has `isAsyncSupported()` set to `true`.

You can set the async attribute in the `HttpServletRequest` object to `true` by:

```
req.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);
```

or

```
((org.apache.catalina.connector.Request)req).setAsyncSupported(true);
```

You also have to add in front of your servlet:

```
@WebServlet(... , asyncSupported = true)
```

Comment: I tested isAsyncSuppported and it returns true.

Comment: Did you try with setting attributes?

Comment: Do you have any filters?

Comment: I have not any filters.

Comment: Do you have     @WebServlet(... , asyncSupported = true)
in front of your servlet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42876/discussion-between-user987339-and-user1902062)

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the response, not the request state, as `startAsync()` cannot be called when the original response is closed.

You should be able to see from your code where is closes the response (e.g. if it calls `response.close();` somewhere). You should call `startAsync()` before this point, or set a flag once it has been called and check that before calling `startAsync()`.

If you do not handle the response at all you can try to test The `HttpServletResponse` to see if it's been closed, but there is no definite way to do that:

```
if (!isClosed(response.getOutputStream())) {
  startAsync();
  // ...
```

For discussion of implementation of `isClosed()`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655901/how-to-check-whether-an-outputstream-is-closed). There is no easy or recommended way, but if you're desparate this may work (untested) but it does write to the response output stream, which is dangerous:

```
boolean isClosed(ServletOutputStream sos) {
  try {
    os.println("");  // This will append extra line feed to the HTTP response!
    return false;
  } catch(IOException e) {
    return true;  // assume due to stream being closed
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can possibly rely on `response.isCommitted()` ([see doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#isCommitted%28%29)) as a committed response would typically be closed, however this isn't definite - it could be closed but not committed.

Comment: Dont works because req.getAsyncContext() returns null. Is it normal?

Comment: Ah sorry, you cannot use getAsyncContext() in this way, sorry. Edited answer but it would help if you would provide more source code for context.